# Persistent data structures in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, immutability

Does anyone know a library or some at least some research on creating and using persistent data structures in Java? I don't refer to persistence as long term storage but persistence in terms of immutability (see [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)).

I'm currently exploring different ways to model an api for persistent structures. Using builders seems to be a interesting solution:

```
// create persistent instance
Person p = Builder.create(Person.class)
             .withName("Joe")
             .withAddress(Builder.create(Address.class)
                 .withCity("paris")
                 .build())
              .build();

// change persistent instance, i.e. create a new one 
Person p2 = Builder.update(p).withName("Jack");

Person p3 = Builder.update(p)
              .withAddress(Builder.update(p.address())
                .withCity("Berlin")
                .build)
            .build();
```

But this still feels somewhat boilerplated. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if the functional-programming tag here is appropriate. I take functional programming to mean languages like Haskell and Lisp. :)

Comment: I think functional because persistent data structures are common to functional programming languages. I'm guessing he wants to be able to do something in Java that he's easily able to do in some functional language.

Why community wiki? This seems like a solid programming question to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the obvious choices are:

o Switch to a transient data structure (builder) for the update. This is quite normal. `StringBuilder` for `String` manipulation for example. As your example.

```
Person p3 =
    Builder.update(p)
    .withAddress(
        Builder.update(p.address())
       .withCity("Berlin")
       .build()
    )
    .build();
```

o Always use persistent structures. Although there appears to be lots of copying, you should actually be sharing almost all state, so it is nowhere near as bad as it looks.

```
final Person p3 = p
    .withAddress(
        p.address().withCity("Berlin")
    );
```

o Explode the data structure into lots of variables and recombine with one huge and confusing constructor.

```
final Person p3 = Person.of(
    p.name(),
    Address.of(
       p.house(), p.street(), "Berlin", p.country()
    ),
    p.x(),
    p.y(),
    p.z()
 );
```

o Use call back interfaces to provide the new data. Even more boilerplate.

```
final Person p3 = Person.of(new PersonInfo(
    public String  name   () { return p.name(); )
    public Address address() { return Address.of(new AddressInfo() {
       private final Address a = p.address();
       public String house  () { return a.house()  ; }
       public String street () { return a.street() ; }
       public String city   () { return "Berlin"   ; }
       public String country() { return a.country(); }
    })),
    public Xxx     x() { return p.x(); }
    public Yyy     y() { return p.y(); }
    public Zzz     z() { return p.z(); }
 });
```

o Use nasty hacks to make fields transiently available to code.

```
final Person p3 = new PersonExploder(p) {{
    a = new AddressExploder(a) {{
        city = "Berlin";
    }}.get();
}}.get();
```

(Funnily enough I was just put down a copy of Purely Functional Data Structures by Chris Okasaki.)

Comment: If we integrate the update method into the persistent type one could even simplyfy this to final Person p3 = p2.withAddress(p3.address().withCity("Berlin")) 

I'm curious if there is a way to omit the duplicate reference to "p3".

Comment: The example shouldn't have had the builder (updated). You could add nasty hacks to get the address, then go back to the person, but that would be evil and confusing. Another nasty hack would be a class that explodes the Person and then uses double brace idiom - not enough characters to describe it.

Comment: Just noting, the double brace initialization is called “nasty” for a reason – it creates a subclass (impact on code size and performance) that often gets a reference to the enclosing object (might cause a memory leak).

Answer (score 12):

Builders will make your code too verbose to be usable. In practice, almost all immutable data structures I've seen pass in state through the constructor. For what its worth, here are a nice series of posts describing immutable data structures in C# (which should convert readily into Java):

- [Part 1: Kinds of Immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx)
- [Part 2: Simple Immutable Stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack.aspx)
- [Part 3: Covariant Immutable Stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/06/immutability-in-c-part-three-a-covariant-immutable-stack.aspx)
- [Part 4: Immutable Queue](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/10/immutability-in-c-part-four-an-immutable-queue.aspx)
- [Part 5: Lolz!](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/13/immutability-in-c-part-five-lolz.aspx) (included for completeness)
- [Part 6: Simple Binary Tree](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/18/immutability-in-c-part-six-a-simple-binary-tree.aspx)
- [Part 7: More on Binary Trees](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/19/immutability-in-c-part-seven-more-on-binary-trees.aspx)
- [Part 8: Even More on Binary Trees](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/01/18/immutability-in-c-part-eight-even-more-on-binary-trees.aspx)
- [Part 9: AVL Tree Implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/01/21/immutability-in-c-part-nine-academic-plus-my-avl-tree-implementation.aspx)
- [Part 10: Double-ended Queue](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/01/22/immutability-in-c-part-10-a-double-ended-queue.aspx)
- [Part 11: Working Double-ended Queue Implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/12/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue.aspx)

C# and Java are extremely verbose, so the code in these articles is quite scary. I recommend learning OCaml, F#, or Scala and familiarizing yourself with immutability with those languages. Once you master the technique, you'll be able to apply the same coding style to Java much more easily.

Comment: What do you mean by "Builders will make your code to verbose to be unusable"? Did you mean to say "too verbose to be usable"? If so, I vehemently disagree. Builders make the code simple, easy to understand and very clear.

Comment: I know scala and haskell so thats some of the motivation to investigate on persistent data structures in java.

Comment: The code to implement builders tends to pointless verbose, certainly. Using builders there is the usual punctuation soup of Java-like languages.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org). Currently provided persistent datastructures include:

- Singly-linked list (fj.data.List)
- Lazy singly-linked list (fj.data.Stream)
- Nonempty list (fj.data.NonEmptyList)
- Optional value (a container of length 0 or 1) (fj.data.Option)
- Set (fj.data.Set)
- Multi-way tree (a.k.a. rose tree) (fj.data.Tree)
- Immutable map (fj.data.TreeMap)
- Products (tuples) of arity 1-8 (fj.P1..P8)
- Vectors of arity 2-8 (fj.data.vector.V2..V8)
- Pointed list (fj.data.Zipper)
- Pointed tree (fj.data.TreeZipper)
- Type-safe, generic heterogeneous list (fj.data.hlist.HList)
- Immutable arrays (fj.data.Array)
- Disjoint union datatype (fj.data.Either)

A number of usage examples are provided with the binary distribution. The source is available under a BSD license from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/functionaljava).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to functional java. However my question was about implementing a persistent object model in gerneral, not about certain (well-known) persistent data structures.

Comment: Instead of "object", think "record" or "struct". A record is basically a heterogeneous list with search-by-type capability. I've been thinking about how to implement that kind of thing in Java as well. Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 5):

I implemented a few persistent data structures in Java. All open source (GPL) on Google code for anyone who is interested:

http://code.google.com/p/mikeralib/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Mikera/src/mikera/persistent

The main ones I have so far are:

- Persistent mutable test object
- Persistent hash maps
- Persistent vectors/lists
- Persistent sets (including a specialised persistent set of ints)

Comment: Took a quick look before deciding to not use it, here is why :
You implemented the base interfaces from Java Collections.
It's better for methods to NOT BE THERE than being blocked with UnsupportedOperationExceptions.

Comment: Interesting viewpoint David.... I felt it was well worth implementing these interfaces so that the persistent data structures can be used with APIs that expect a Java collection (which is quite a lot of APIs, including many of the core Java APIs!)

If you do want that API compatibility, there isn't much choice other than to throw a UnsupportedOperationException - however I think that is a good thing because if someone tries to modify an immutable collection then there is clearly some bug in their logic that they should be fixing!

Comment: Yes, for API compatibilty UnsupportedOperationExceptions are the way.
But it doesn't have to be the principal classes which are compatible, wrapper classes backed by your own will do as well.
Then you have compatibilty when you need it, and the rest of the time, classes which communicate their immutability at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Follow a very simple tentative with dynamic proxy:

```
class ImmutableBuilder {

    static <T> T of(Immutable immutable) {
        Class<?> targetClass = immutable.getTargetClass();
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(targetClass.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{targetClass},
            immutable);
    }

    public static <T> T of(Class<T> aClass) {
        return of(new Immutable(aClass, new HashMap<String, Object>()));
    }
}

class Immutable implements InvocationHandler {

    private final Class<?> targetClass;
    private final Map<String, Object> fields;

    public Immutable(Class<?> aTargetClass, Map<String, Object> immutableFields) {
        targetClass = aTargetClass;
        fields = immutableFields;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (method.getName().equals("toString")) { 
            // XXX: toString() result can be cached
            return fields.toString();
        }

        if (method.getName().equals("hashCode")) { 
            // XXX: hashCode() result can be cached
            return fields.hashCode();
        }

        // XXX: naming policy here
        String fieldName = method.getName(); 

        if (method.getReturnType().equals(targetClass)) {
          Map<String, Object> newFields = new HashMap<String, Object>(fields);
          newFields.put(fieldName, args[0]);
          return ImmutableBuilder.of(new Immutable(targetClass, newFields));
        } else {
            return fields.get(fieldName);
        }
    }

    public Class<?> getTargetClass() {
        return targetClass;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
interface Person {
    String name();
    Person name(String name);
    int age();
    Person age(int age);
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person mark = ImmutableBuilder.of(Person.class).name("mark").age(32);
        Person john = mark.name("john").age(24);
        System.out.println(mark);
        System.out.println(john);
    }
}
```

grow directions:

- naming policy (getName, withName, name)
- caching toString(), hashCode()
- equals() implementations should be straightforward (although not implemented)

hope it helps :)

Comment: That's how I actually implemented a proof of concept on persisent data structures. I found this the simple part. What I did not find was an elegant api to "update" a field of an persistent instance, i.e. create a copy of the instance with only a certain field changed.

Comment: sorry I've misunderstood your question! :-( 
By the way writing this code was very funny and an useful exercise :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult, if not impossible, to make things immutable that ain't designed so.

If you can design from ground up:

- use only final fields
- do not reference non immutable objects

Answer (score 0):

Do you want immutability :

1. so external code cannot change the data?
2. so once set a value cannot be changed?

In both cases there are easier ways to accomplish the desired result.

Stopping external code from changing the data is easy with interfaces:

```
public interface Person {
   String getName();
   Address getAddress();
}
public interface PersonImplementor extends Person {
   void setName(String name);
   void setAddress(Address address);
}

public interface Address {
    String getCity();
}


public interface AddressImplementor {
    void setCity(String city);
}
```

Then to stop changes to a value once set is also "easy" using java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference (although hibernate or some other persistence layer usage may need to be modified):

```
class PersonImpl implements PersonImplementor {
    private AtomicReference<String> name;
    private AtomicReference<Address> address;

    public void setName(String name) {
        if ( !this.name.compareAndSet(name, name) 
           && !this.name.compareAndSet(null, name)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("name already set to "+this.name.get()+" cannot set to "+name);
        }
    }
    // .. similar code follows....
}
```

But why do you need anything more than just interfaces to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0):

Google Guava now hosts a variety of [immutable/persistent data structures](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained).

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/Paguro for persistent data structures for Java.

Some of the other answers suggested libraries for immutability, which is fine but not what asked for. Paguro is a library that provide true persistent data structure that allow mutation and still preserve the previous version of itself!